# What's the "p" permission found on /var/run/screen/ ...?

Tags: linux, shell

I was wondering if I can do a tail on screen session files,
so I went into `/var/run/screen/S-Username`.

This is what I found on that directory (using `ll -l`)

```
XXXX@ubuntu:/var/run/screen/S-XXXX $ ll -a
total 0
drwx------ 2 XXXX XXXX 60 XXXX  5 09:42 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 root utmp 60 XXXX  5 09:42 ../
prwx------ 1 XXXX XXXX  0 XXXX  5 09:42 3031.pts-1.ubuntu
```

[image: What permission is this?]

I’ve tried googling for “Linux file permissions”,
and no one seems to mention the `p` flag. Can anyone
tell me what the `p` permission flag is?

P.S: Also, it seems that I can’t do `cat` or `tail` on that file either.

Comment: It's better to include text in your question rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @KeithThompson but... freehand circles!

Comment: @hobbs: Doesn't count unless they're red. 8-)}

Comment: I wouldn't expect `cat` or `tail` to show anything for a file whose size is reported as *zero* bytes, whether it's a pipe or not.

Answer (score 12):

`p` stands for FIFO, a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe). So it's not a permission, but a file type (just like `d` for directory).

You can't use `cat` or `tail` to get its content, because a FIFO isn't a regular file, it's used for inter-process communication.

Answer (score 12):

It's not a permission. The `p` means that it's a [named pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/7/fifo), not a regular file.